# Design of maven plugin that generates Java sources from XML files in src/main/resources

Tags: maven, code-generation, classpath, maven-plugin

I'm working on a Maven plugin for [JCasGen](http://uima.apache.org/d/uimaj-2.4.0/tools.html#ugr.tools.jcasgen), which takes an XML type system description file and generates some Java classes. The type system description file often points to other type system description files in the same project [via the classpath](http://uima.apache.org/d/uimaj-2.4.0/references.html#ugr.ref.xml.component_descriptor.imports). JCasGen therefore needs a classpath containing all the XML type system description files in order to run. (These XML files must also be placed in the project's final jar file because Java code may refer to them via the classpath too.)

The XML files are in `src/main/resources` so that Maven will copy them over to `target/classes` and they will be included in the project's jar file. So the natural classpath to give to the plugin would be `target/classes`. However, if my plugin runs at the intuitive `generate-sources` phase, then the XML files in `src/main/resources` will not yet have been copied to `target/classes`, and JCasGen will fail.

So how do I structure things so that I can give the right classpath to JCasGen?

Here are a couple things I've thought of, but I don't really know whether they make sense:

1. Run the plugin on the `process-resources` phase, and just use `target/classes` for the classpath. This is what I'm currently doing and it seems to work. (I was worried about ensuring that my plugin always runs after the standard Maven copying of resources, but that seems to be what happens by default.) The main problem with this approach is that `process-resources` is not the intuitive phase for a plugin that generates sources.
2. Build a classpath by concatenating the resource directories and `target/classes`:

   ```
   StringBuilder classpath = new StringBuilder();
   for (Resource resource : this.project.getBuild().getResources()) {
     classpath.append(resource.getDirectory());
     classpath.append(File.pathSeparatorChar);
   }
   classpath.append(this.project.getBuild().getOutputDirectory());
   ```

   I tried something like this and it seemed to work, but I worry that this could fail for complicated resources with includes or excludes.

Comment: I read the JCasGen docs you linked to and I cannot really see that the classpath has to be given. I think you should put the XML-files in some other folder (they are not resources that is needed after the build) and pass them to the JCasGen and just let it output the generated source to `target/src-generated/` or `target/generated-sources`. And then let them be compiled. I don't really see the point of having XML-files part of the classpath.

Comment: They really do have to be in the jar, or import by name will fail: "If an import specifies a name attribute, the value of that attribute should take the form of a Java-style dotted name (e.g. org.apache.myproj.MyTypeSystem). An .xml file with this name will be searched for in the classpath..." http://uima.apache.org/d/uimaj-2.4.0/references.html#ugr.ref.xml.component_descriptor.imports

Comment: So create a multi module project. The first module just takes the xml files from the resources and place them in the jar. Next module depends on first module and uses the plugin you have created. XML files will be on classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run the plugin on the `process-resources` phase. This solution is used by other plugins that generate sources and require access to the classpath:

- GWT Maven Plugin [gwt:resources](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/resources-mojo.html) and [gwt:mergewebxml](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/mergewebxml-mojo.html) goals
- jDTAUS Container Mojo [spring-descriptor](http://www.jdtaus.org/1.0.x/jdtaus-core/jdtaus-container-mojo/spring-descriptor-mojo.html) goal

Note though that to get the classpath you should use `project.getCompileClasspathElements()`, not `project.getBuild().getOutputDirectory()`. The former will make sure you get, e.g. the `target/classes` directories of projects on which the current project depends.

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand your question and I'm adding this as an aswer to be able to format it properly (so please don't vote unless it's of actual use!).

I do know that your plugin should run during the generate-sources phase: it's the correct phase, full stop :).

The maven standard says that generated code should go under target/generated-sources/, for example the [jaxb2 plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/xjc-mojo.html) puts the files under target/generated-sources/jaxb and maven adds this folder automatically during compilation.

I suggest you to look at the jaxb2 plugin to find some guidance.

Comment: Yeah, the plugin is set to the `generate-sources` phase, and it writes the generated sources to `target/generated-sources/jcasgen`. But to run the plugin, I need a classpath that contains all the resources from `src/main/resources`. Normally, that would just be `target/classes`, but Maven doesn't put resources there until *after* the `generate-sources` phase.

Answer (score 1):

Create a multi module project where the first module just copies the xml files into a jar. The second module uses that jar as input and execute the plugin.

```
.
├── pom.xml
├── xml
|   ├── pom.xml
|   └── src
|       └── main
|           └── resources
|               └── com
|                   └── stackoverflow
|                       ├── package1
|                       |   └── FirstClass.xml
|                       └── package2
|                           └── SecondClass.xml
└── gen
    └── pom.xml
```

`pom.xml`

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>Q12682078</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</name>

    <modules>
        <module>xml</module>
        <module>gen</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
                <artifactId>Q12682078-xml</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

`xml/pom.xml`

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>Q12682078</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>Q12682078-xml</artifactId>

    <name>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</name>
</project>
```

`gen/pom.xml`

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>Q12682078</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>Q12682078-gen</artifactId>

    <name>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>Q12682078-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- your plugin that now has the xml files in the classpath -->
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Interesting approach. I guess that's possible, but asking people to create two projects for what is conceptually one project isn't great.

Comment: @Steve This is a common way of doing it with maven. I have done several code generation projects with this model. And the result will be one jar to be used in the end. The xml-jar is not really being used after the generation. And since the xml-files are packaged inside a jar then you could let someone else use them to generate something different.

Comment: The xml jar *will* be used after the generation - users of the code will also reference type systems via the classpath. Of course, with the multi-module approach, this still works out okay since the XML jar will be picked up as a transitive dependency.

Comment: @Steve OK then I guess you're fine with this approach?

Comment: I believe that it will work, but I'm not really fine with it because anyone who uses my plugin will now be forced to split their existing projects into two separate projects. (In the standard UIMA project setup, the XML descriptors are in the same project as the code, so I'd have to teach the entire UIMA ecosystem a new way of organizing their projects.)